# Here's a question about the solow model

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, solow

At first, I was confused by how y keeps increasing after depreciation exceeds savings, then I finally found what was truly bothering me. The fact that when depreciation exceeds savings, capital per worker should be negatively affected whereas, in reality, it keeps increasing along the x-axis.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

The following graph shows a point at which the total amount of depreciation is greater than savings. This *decreases* the amount of capital per effective worker, over time, shown by the arrow pointing downwards and to the left.

[image: Solow growth with depreciation higher than savings]